# Typescript function decorator change parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have the following function decorator declared:

```
export function WithAlpha(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>) {
  const method = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function (...args)  {
    return method.apply(this, ['alpha']);
  }
}
```

I try to test it on this class:

```
export class AlphaCl {
  @WithAlpha
  async someMethod(alpha: string) {
    console.log(alpha);
  }
}
```

But instead of getting alpha in the console.log I get undefined. **How can I change function params using the decorator?**

Answer (score 0):

Type of `descriptor` should be updated. Also, `method` should be checked

```js
function WithAlpha(target: AlphaCl, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(alpha: string) => Promise<void>>) {
  const method = descriptor.value;
  if (method) {
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      return method.apply(this, ['alpha']);
    }
  }
}

class AlphaCl {
  @WithAlpha
  async someMethod(alpha: string) {
    console.log(alpha);
  }
}
```